# Email sent twice on trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I have a requirement where I'm sending an email and also creating an email message record when certain conditions meet. However, the email is shot twice and 2 email message records are being created. Where am I going wrong?

```
        public static void SendEmail(List<case> ListofCase) {


    list<case> ListABCases = new list<case>();
    for(Case caseObj: ListofCase)
    {

        if(caseObj.status == 'Open' caseObj.check_arb == false)
        {                                        
                    ListArbitrationCases.add(caseObj);

                }
            }


    //get Email Template Id
    EmailTemplate objEmailTemplate = [SELECT id 
                                     FROM EmailTemplate 
                                     WHERE DeveloperName =: 'VF_check1Temp' 
                                     LIMIT 1];

    List<case> caseList = new List<case>();
    List<Id> listOfContactIds=new List<Id>{};
    case cse = new case();

    for(case caseObj1 : ListABCases) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage objSendEmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    List<String> toAddresses = new List<String> ();
    toAddresses.add(label.Recipients1);
    toAddresses.add(label.Recipients2);
    objSendEmail.setTemplateId(objEmailTemplate.id);
    objSendEmail.setWhatId(caseObj1.ID);
    objSendEmail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    objSendEmail.setBccSender(false);
    objSendEmail.setUseSignature(false);
    system.debug('save as activity' +objSendEmail.saveAsActivity );
    objSendEmail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    objSendEmail.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
    objSendEmail.setTargetObjectId(userinfo.getuserID());
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] listemails = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {objSendEmail};
    Messaging.sendEmail(listemails);  

    EmailMessage emailMsg = new EmailMessage(); 
    emailMsg.ToAddress = string.valueOf(listemails[0].getToAddresses());
    emailMsg.FromName = String.valueOf(UserInfo.getName());
    emailMsg.FromAddress = UserInfo.getUserEmail();
    emailMsg.Subject=listemails[0].getSubject();
    emailMsg.HtmlBody=listemails[0].getHtmlBody();
    emailMsg.ParentId = caseObj1.ID; //Attach with the case
    emailMsg.MessageDate = system.now();
    emailMsg.Status = '3';
    insert emailMsg;
    cse.Id = caseObj1.id;
    cse.check_arb = true; 
    caseList.add(cse);
        system.debug('email message'+emailMsg);

     }  
   update caseList;



}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of which trigger event you're calling this from and whether or not there's trigger recursion or workflow updates, I think the solution is going to be the same: you need to use a static collection variable to identify Cases for which you've already sent emails during this transaction, and use that to suppress duplication.

In your handler, you'd declare a `static Set<Id> casesAlreadyProcessed;`

In `SendEmail()`, you'd change your criteria for processing each Case:

```
    if(caseObj.status == 'Open' caseObj.check_arb == false)
```

(Note there's a missing operator there).

to also check `!casesAlreadyProcessed.contains(caseObj.Id)`. Then, inside your `if`, where you add the Case to your list of Cases to process, you'd also do `casesAlreadyProcessed.add(caseObj.Id)`.

That ensures that an email gets sent exactly once per transaction per Case.

Additionally, I'll not that you need to move your `Messaging.sendEmail()` call out of the loop. You only get 10 calls to that method per transaction, so you need to bulkify this as well.